# Как создать двумерный динамический массив типа List?

Tags: c#, list

Подскажите, как создать двумерный динамический массив типа List, чтобы он принимал в обоих случаях только значения, а не другие массивы?

Звучит взаимоисключающе, но в Python можно было сделать так:

```
list[0][0] = 1;
```

Причем мне нужно, чтобы по первому индексу были строки `List[0....n].Add(string)`, а по индексу `List[0....n][0....n].Add(int)`.

Это мне необходимо для работы с данными. Первая строка - это будет идентификатор колонок, остальные же строки будут числами. С которыми будут постоянно проводиться операции, также таблица не будет записываться сразу массивами, в нее данные будут добавляться не равномерно, и также неравномерно высчитываться. Т.е. объявление `List<List<string>>>` мне не подходит. Нужен вариант что-то типа такого `List<string<int>>`, на крайний случай `List<string<string>>`

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужен `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`

Comment: Это конечно, из разряда мой мозг не думал в этом направлении. А что так можно было?)) Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать класс и на его основе получать список List.

```
public class TwoStrings
{
   public string String_1 {get;set;}
   public string String_2 {get;set;}

   public TwoStrings(string string_1, string string_2)
   {
      String_1 = string_1;
      String_2 = string_2;
   }
}
```

Далее создаем коллекцию и используем

```
List<TwoStrings> collection = new List<TwoStrings>();

collection.Add(new TwoStrings("One", "Two");
```

List будет принимать и хранить 2 строки.
Потом можно будет сериализовать при необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо, за вашу реализацию данного вопроса, сохранил себе в конспекты.